# IAM policy for specific EC2 instances acces

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instances (M1 & M2) and two IAM users(U1 & U2) and I want to make a policy to specify U1 can access M1 only and U2 can access M2 only. But no luck. Can anyone assist on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Do you mean login? Are they Windows or Linux instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in various ways.

If by "access" you mean OS login then you can use Windows\Linux user login restrictions.
If by "access" you mean controlling the machine (start\stop etc.) you can and need to use IAM policy and restrict it by IAM user.
You can also use Security Groups to restrict access to specific ports from different or specific IP's.
You also wrote "no luck", what have you tried already?

Hope that gives a little idea about the options.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common use case, and AWS has published articles and videos around this but please note that other IAM users will be able to see the (resource) in this case Instances, launched by any other IAM user, but they will not be able to perform action (stop/start/terminate/reboot) over it.

As of now there is no such option that limits IAM users to restrict to see Instances launched by other IAM users.

[1] Can I restrict the access of IAM users to specific EC2 resources?
        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ragz-TekLBM

[2] Can I restrict the access of IAM users to specific Amazon EC2 resources?
        https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-ec2-iam/